# ares-inspect luna-send command failed

Tags: television, webos, lg

I'm trying to debug my webos3 tv but I keep getting the following error:

```
ares-inspect --device web30 com.starz.lgtv.app_0.0.1_all.ipk 
ares-inspect ERR! ares-inspect: Error: luna-send command failed (not exist)
```

It doesn't say anywhere in the documentation what luna-send is and it's closed source. I'm running on mac using the cli for webos. Is there anything I need to install?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By trial and error, I found that you need to omit the version numbers for it to work:

```
ares-inspect --device web30 com.starz.lgtv.app --open
```

Don't forget the `--open` argument to open the inspector. :-)

The documentation doesn't explicitly say that you need to omit it but it is inferred in the demo code:

http://webostv.developer.lge.com/sdk/using-webos-tv-cli/debugging-web-applications-cli/

Comment: I removed the version number and .ipk but still I'm getting the same error. any thoughts?

Comment: Did you remove  the suffix "_all" too ?

Comment: you're a genius ! just saved my day

Answer (score 1):

It's not about omitting version or removing suffixes from filenames. You should use the *app id* here, same as in your appinfo.json file.

```
ares-inspect [OPTION...] [--app|-a] APP_ID

APP_ID = ID of the app whose information is to be viewed using Web Inspector.
```

See http://webostv.developer.lge.com/sdk/tools/using-webos-tv-cli/ for reference.